# How to find names of Unincorporated parts of a county in Navteq data?

Tags: geoprocessing

I am currently using Navteq Data and am unable to find how to label unincorporated places within the LA County. Most of these spots are small and spread throughout the entire county however they do have well known names, most times these are same as neighboring cities.

Has any one had similar problem? i.e. how to label the unincorporated parts of any county?

Thanks,
Shakira

Answer (score 1):

Look for the 'Hamlet' layer; these are points that have a POI_Name field which represents community/localities versus incorporated cities.

Answer (score 0):

I would try NAVTEQ Census Boundaries™; they are derived from US Census Tiger Data (which would have political boundaries).